# Confused when move constructor is called?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I have been struggling with this question for a while and I cant find an explanation to this.
Suppose I have the following code

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {std::cout << "Regular constructor \n";}

    foo( const foo& a)                            //In abscence of const keyword the copy constructor is called
    {std::cout << "Copy constructor \n";}

    foo& operator=(const foo& a) 
    {std::cout << "Copy Assignment operator \n";}

    foo(foo&& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor \n";
    }

    foo& operator=(foo&& a) 
    {std::cout << "Move Assignment operator \n";}

    int a;
};


foo myfunction()
{
    foo d;
    d.a =120;
    return d;
}
```

Now if I do something like this

```
foo a = myfunction();
```

Here is what I would expect. myfunction() returns back an object lvalue however since myfunction() is temporary it would return back an rvalue. Am I correct ? Now in this case the move constructor would be called and this makes sense. However if I remove the `const` keyword from the copy constructor the copy constructor is called instead of the move constructor. Could anyone please explain to me why this happens ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get rid of the undefined behavior by including `return *this;` in your `operator=()` implementations, then I get what I would expect, which is one call to the no-argument constructor. Because of copy-ellison.

Comment: Present a complete compileable example, and tell what compiler and options you are using.

Comment: `myfunction` is blatantly declared to return a prvalue, not an lvalue.

Comment: I heard that VS2012 doesn't do copy elision in Debug mode, in some situations

Comment: Could someone please help, I am using GCC compiler and c++14 version in my machine and trying to invoke `foo a = myfunction(); ` But I am not able to get a call in the `move constructor/move assignment operator`. I searched it in the forum but I could only find the discussion in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS2012 has a nasty extension that allows temporaries to bind to lvalue-references. We can't reproduce with modern, standard-conforming compilers, which in fact *elide* the call to the copy/move-constructor (because of [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)). Applying the option `fno-elide-constructors` shows that they do indeed call the move-constructor even with the absence of `const`.

Comment: Yes i am trying it here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/821f765277097b35 and I do get a different result

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

The move constructor is called whenever an object is initialized from xvalue of the same type, which includes:

- initialization, T a = std::move(b); or T a(std::move(b));, where b is of type T
- function argument passing: f(std::move(a));, where a is of type T and f is void f(T t)
- function return: return a; inside a function such as T f(), where a is of type T which has a move constructor.